# Microsoft Access database processing slow even over fast network

Tags: networking, nas, speed, microsoft-access

A Microsoft Access database file has about 20 MB size and total of 4000 records in few tables. Does not look like a big deal.

However, why this database has 3-5 times longer processing times when it is stored on network storage (NAS) instead of local drive? LAN bandwidth is 1 GB/s, what was also verified by testing.

Comment: Bandwidth is not the only relevant things. Latency also count. And latency is likely a lot higher over the LAN.

Comment: I'd put money on this being SMB overhead, without tweaking SMB can really slow you down. If you require performance use an iSCSI mount instead of an SMB share.